# docker build image not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

When attempting to build an image from a Dockerfile in PyCharm the following error is shown

```
Deploying 'test1 Dockerfile: Dockerfile'...
Building image...
Failed to deploy 'test1 Dockerfile: Dockerfile': com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Failed to parse docker configuration file<br/>caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to parse docker config.json
```

Building outside of PyCharm from the command line works fine.

I assume I'm meant to set the location of the .docker/config.json file, but I don't see where in PyCharm to do that.

*Versions*

- PyCharm Community 2018.2.1
- PyCharm Docker plugin  182.3684.90
- Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried to delete `~/.docker/config.json` and restart docker service? myabe you want to make a backup copy of that just in case.

Comment: Oddly that did actually work, and I only lost access to one of the two private registries. Doing a `docker login` got me access back to the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something could have tempered with `~/.docker/config.json`. Try deleting it and restarting the docker service afterwards.

You might want to `docker login` again in case you were logged in to some private registries.